# Different UTM limits

Tags: coordinate-system

Why is there a difference of 4 degrees between the UTM North / South cut-offs?
One might expect the North and South UPS grids to be symmetrical in coverage but they followed the UTM decision to stop at 84 N and 80 S, did they not?

Comment: There really isn't much below 80 south besides penguins but there's a lot going on above 80 north (Greenland, parts of Russia, parts of Canada).

Comment: So no technical reason?

Comment: It's MGRS that switches over to polar stereographic at 80S/84N, not UTM.

Comment: Now you have really confused me!   cf https://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm      We don't use the American military grid down here!     I am trying to explain to 14 year olds why the UTM maps don't go all the way to the Poles. I don't know the answer to why the Northerners dont use the UPS system, but use an UTM based on 3 degree slices.

Comment: Yeah, that's wrong. It's not UTM,  but MGRS. And NATO and other American allies use MGRS as well (then DMA, now NGA created the maps to be shared, and they're used for disaster relief, tool).

Comment: In the Wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_polar_stereographic_coordinate_system it mentions that the UPS grid covers the area not covered by UTM grids, UTM grids don't go as far south as north because there's not much there worth gridding; the land was gridded first and then the UPS grid was created to cover the ungridded area so there's no gaps or overlap. I'm fairly sure an early teen would understand that explanation.